# What is error ID: -78170657

Tags: error-messages

Logging into Salesforce generates this error:

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: -78170657)

This happens on initial page load. Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: Errors like this are not publicly available; they are unique IDs generated by the logging system in Salesforce. You need to contact Support or someone with access to these codes to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Salesforce Internal Server - What's in a GACK?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161605/salesforce-internal-server-whats-in-a-gack)

Comment: Have you tried looking at the browser console to see if you have more information about an error from a component in the page?

Answer (score 0):

The GACKs(-78170657)(-745221428)were reported by multiple customers. It is related to the "Service Disruption - Multiple Instances Using Lightning CDN" that was also posted https://status.salesforce.com/generalmessages/962

Per trust site, issue is resolved at 01:26 UTC, on May 12, 2022. Please clear your cache and cookies, then reload your browser and attempt to access Salesforce.