# I'm encountering a Gack error, have the ID but need more information to resolve

Tags: gack

GACK - Error ID: 2133272047-66961 (-125565929)

I believe this is happening when the flow is trying to create a record.  After a decision path, the flow is intended to create a record but upon submission, I'm seeing a record is not being created.  I'm not sure this is the issue in the error, but this is something off I am seeing with this flow.  Hopefully this may help with context for this error, but would like to know what exactly is behind this error ID.  Thanks.

Comment: GACK errors generally mean that you'll need to go through Salesforce's official Customer Support. We're mostly customers of Salesforce like yourself, so the error Id is not meaningful to most of us. There is one Salesforce employee that does occasionally answer/comment on these, but the sure bet would be to open a case with Customer Support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Salesforce Internal Server - What's in a GACK?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161605/salesforce-internal-server-whats-in-a-gack)

Comment: Gack error numbers tell a sslesforce.com engineer where the code crashed and what log files to look at. They aren't otherwise assigned meaning, such as you'd see with Microsoft products, for example.

Comment: @DerekF I was hoping that it would be identified as I've seen other GACK errors posted.

Comment: @sfdcfox I read through the link, thank you.  Looks like I need to log a case with Salesforce.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely the appropriate route, unless you know someone in R&D that you can ask directly.