# When creating new site, b2b commerce lightning template gives error

Tags: force.com-sites, commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce, lwr, b2b

I am trying to create a new site from all sites.

If I choose B2B Commerce (LWR) template, it gives me an error when site setup.

**An unexpected error occurred. Try again or contact your Salesforce administrator for help.
Error: 1956534952-114875 (1079661603)**

If I choose another template, site setup completes without any error.

My commerce settings are enabled.

Tried B2B Permission sets but didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Salesforce Internal Server - What's in a GACK?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161605/salesforce-internal-server-whats-in-a-gack)