# An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1884642260-375043 (1535387224) (deployment)

Tags: deployment, error, gack, unexpectedexception

Hi have an issue when deploying a flow from a sandbox to another :

> An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1884642260-375043 (1535387224)

Could you help identify what is wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: Nope, most of us here can't do a thing with that error. What you have there is called a _GACK_. The first two numbers (separated by a hyphen) are the "event id", and the second number (in the parens) is a stack trace identifier. Both of those are really only relevant to Salesforce's official customer support (99.9% of us here are customers of Salesforce, like yourself. Not Salesforce employees). If you're lucky, you may be able to find more info by searching for the number in the parentheses. Beyond that, this is something to open a support ticket with Salesforce for.

Comment: What you are seeing is a [GACK](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack) . From Salesforce backend logs for the stacktrace Id `1535387224` 
 I see message as `Metadata gack caused by: NullPointerException` `java.lang.NullPointerException on id 3011w000000jx4Q`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Internal Server Error - What's in a GACK?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161605/internal-server-error-whats-in-a-gack)

Comment: It partially answer to my question. It gives me the failing flow Id version, but it does not help me to find where is the NullPointerException exactly in my flow. Could you help ?

Comment: if you can, either a) rebuild the flow manually in the target sandbox, piece-by-piece; this may help identify the issue (as there is some environment difference). b) verify both sandboxes are on the same SFDC version; or c) simplifiy the flow in the source sandbox and deploy, then add back pieces until you get a failure. Your issue is on an object whose key prefix is 301 which is `InteractionDefinitionVersion`

Comment: I found the issue by deconstructing the flow piece by piece in the source ord and testing the deployment for every piece removed from the flow. A field was missing in my change set. Thank you guys for the help

Comment: Consider posting this as an answer. It'll help anyone else with the same error code in the future.

Comment: @SwethaMaddali how you got smth like 'Metadata gack caused by: NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException on id 3011w000000jx4Q'?

Comment: @Mamed As a salesforce employee, I was able to check the internal tool for GACK ID for the stack trace

Comment: @SwethaMaddali Sounds good! Is there chance you can check another error id?

Comment: @Mamed Sure, Give me the details

Comment: @SwethaMaddali 1.  An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 167664719-3051922 (-741512385) tlite_logo_full1: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 167664719-3051922 (-741512385)

Comment: @SwethaMaddali Will be surprised if it works!

Comment: For the provided stacktrace, I see details as `java.lang.IllegalStateException: bulkDml: received EntityObjects that do not refer to current UddInfo: ContentDistribution(contentDistribution) on id 03S..........`(masked the id intentionally)

Comment: @SwethaMaddali Thanks! What we can do or where to request you to officially get this full error? We need that id

Comment: Please [log a case with Salesforce support](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workcom_contact_support.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue by deconstructing the flow piece by piece in the source org and testing the deployment for every piece removed from the flow. A field was missing in my change set. The answer from Swetha helped me a lot too. Thanks