# Data Cloud Gack

Tags: gack, datacloud

I am in trial Data Cloud instance and I am trying to save item mappings in a data stream, and I am getting the following error:

Unable to save, please try again. GackId: 1245455458-20595 (-1687897127)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Internal Server Error - What's in a GACK?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161605/internal-server-error-whats-in-a-gack)

Comment: Can you make sure you are mapping all in one go-  like we have to map contact point email, individual and party identification in one go