# Salesforce Error ID: 2046021028-569681 (-1183289157)

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, query

When create a get record on Salesforce Flow with multiple case field i have this error :
--> Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to look up records: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 2046021028-569680 (-548403183). You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

Here is the query i need to do : **OR Condition**

- Check in Account table all the account containing the Case.CustomerEmail__c or Case.SuppliedEmail on Account.PersonEmail || Account.OtherEmail__pc
- Check in Account table all the account containing the Case.Phone or Case.SuppliedPhone on Account.Phone || Account.Phone2__pc|| Account.Phone3__pc || Account.PersonMobilePhone
- When trying this query with Salesforce Inspector => It **works**
- When trying this query with Salesforce Dev Console => it **Works**
- When trying in a Flow Get Component => It **Fails**

**Here is my Apex Query** :

```
SELECT Id, Name, PersonEmail, Phone from Account WHERE ((PersonEmail != null AND PersonEmail = 'test@test.com') OR (OtherEmail__pc = 'test@test.com' AND OtherEmail__pc != null)) OR ((Phone = '' AND Phone != null) OR (Phone2__pc = '' AND Phone2__pc != null) OR (Phone3__pc = '' AND Phone3__pc != null) OR (PersonMobilePhone = '' AND PersonMobilePhone != null))
```

**Here is my Flow get component screen shot** :

[image]

**Variable Content** :

CaseCustomerEmail :

```
IF(NOT(ISBLANK({!GetCaseInfos.SuppliedEmail})), {!GetCaseInfos.SuppliedEmail},IF(NOT(ISBLANK({!GetCaseInfos.CustomerEmail__c})),{!GetCaseInfos.CustomerEmail__c},IF(NOT(ISBLANK({!GetCaseInfos.SuppliedEmail__c})),{!GetCaseInfos.SuppliedEmail__c},IF(NOT(ISBLANK({!GetCaseInfos.ContactEmail})),{!GetCaseInfos.ContactEmail},""))))
```

CaseCustomerPhone :

```
IF(NOT(ISBLANK({!GetCaseInfos.SuppliedPhone})), {!GetCaseInfos.SuppliedPhone},IF(NOT(ISBLANK({!GetCaseInfos.Phone__c})),{!GetCaseInfos.Phone__c} , IF(NOT(ISBLANK({!GetCaseInfos.ContactPhone})), {!GetCaseInfos.ContactPhone}, "" )))
```

--> Can you help me with this error ?

Many Thanks.
J.

Comment: This is a _GACK error_, and you pretty much need to get Salesforce support to look into it. 99% of us here are customers of Salesforce like yourself, and can't do anything with this type of error. Outside of Salesforce's official customer support, you may be able to find an answer if you search for the error number that appears in the parenthesis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Internal Server Error - What's in a GACK?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161605/internal-server-error-whats-in-a-gack)