# Scheduled flow kicks off record triggered flow. Failure:

Tags: visual-workflow, governorlimits, limits

I have a scheduled flow that runs daily and checks a box on a filtered set of cases. There are about 200 cases it should find and execute on given the filter conditions. Then I have a record triggered flow that fires based off of that field getting checked. It has a decision element that further breaks out these cases and sends an email alert down each path based off of what kind of case it is.

I am getting failures on the scheduled flow that say:

You or your organization has exceeded the maximum limit for this feature. Error ID: 756852293-358368 (-1837209532)anization has exceeded the maximum limit for this feature. Error ID: 756852293-358368 (-1837209532). You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---The flow tried to update these records: *CASE RECORD ID*. This error occurred: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER: We can't save this record because the *RECORD TRIGGERED FLOW NAME* process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. Limit Exceeded

This whole process works in our full sandbox, but not in production. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your orgid?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Internal Server Error - What's in a GACK?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161605/internal-server-error-whats-in-a-gack)

Comment: hitting daily outbound email limit?  If you have debug on when the scheduled flow runs, you should / might be able to see the Limit failure