# Get Records step in flow fails with "No Records Found" and exception code 231671529-59965 (977953077). Query in workbench fetches records

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, flow-screen-component

(I am an advanced level Salesforce dev/architect. Have developed several flows in the same org and deployed, never had such issues! But this is new since the Monday of this week):

This is a flow I am developing in the sandbox and some spooky things are happening (I am in no mood for Halloween black magic!!)

1. For a while, the flow was working fine but it suddenly stopped working in Get Records element.
2. The record exists; and the query is selective. I look up an Opportunity record with Id = 'xxxxx' AND RecordTypeId = 'yyyyy'.
3. The same query in Workbench fetched the correct record (by definition there is only ONE record!)
4. In the flow, I am getting "No records found" message and subsequent logic fails.
5. The error is :
   "Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to look up records: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 231671529-61344 (977953077). You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide."
   -- Not to mention that I did not find the source of documentation where this error is explained.

I have tried creating a new flow with the same logic, it works initially, then as I go on adding more detail of the logic, at some point it begins to fail the Get Records step.

This is sandbox and we are right in the midst of Winter24 upgrade. Any idea on known issues? I suspect that some editing corrupts the Get Records query/SOAP call without warning.

I logged off, took a break and turned off/turned on the flow. Made a copy of the flow to another, but the failure continues. I believe that the underlying flow code has been corrupted and there is no way for me to fix it!

I tried deleting the element (was a pain because had to remove ALL its references in the flow logic), created a new Get Records element, and tried using it, to no avail.

I am really hassled due to this. Have wasted 2 days already going through the senseless debugging.

---

Addendum by the OP:

Hello everyone! I think I found the issue after some debugging: Essentially, my flow logic is that I need to create multiple child opportunities for my calling opportunity, and therefore, I am building a Collection of data values from the parent opportunity, then loop through it and generate a child opportunity per collection item. I add them to a separate Opportunity collection as I go, and later use Create Records to persist this collection.

About 60% of child's information is same as the parent, therefore I "clone" the parent(calling) opportunity inside the loop. (During my debugging I also removed the Loop Through Collection element and substituted the manual decision-based loop logic - apparently the built-in loop also was contributing to the problem).

The first Create Records step to persist these records seems to corrupt the flow logic/memory and the subsequent Get Records steps fail.

My guess is either -- 1. Cloning is not creating physical copies but is leaving some opportunity references, thus corrupting the opportunities, or 2. Collection of child records all seem to be the same physical copy of the record in memory. These are my guesses; but after removing the Create Records step momentarily, the Get Records error disappeared, and everything (in the incomplete flow) works ok.

Anyhow -- some research needed on how the flow creates physical copies versus references to an existing object, etc.

Comment: That's a GACK error and as painful as the process may be, you really need to go through Salesforce's official support channel to get help with it. There is one Salesforce employee that goes out of their way to respond to GACKs here, but going through support is the sure-fire way to get a response. If you're lucky, you may be able to search for the number in the parenthesis (i.e. `salesforce error 977935077`) to get some insight, but the chances you'll find something are quite low.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Internal Server Error - What's in a GACK?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161605/internal-server-error-whats-in-a-gack)

Comment: is this a screen flow or a record trigger flow?

Comment: Hello everyone, I found the issue after some debugging. I have updated the main question (because my description of the issue exceeded the character limit).

Comment: @prem22: This is a screen flow; but really the only reason for creating a screen flow is so that it gets invoked from a record page. HTH