# Error when publishen translated CMS content

Tags: translation, digital-experience

[CMS Content]

I have a News Detail that is translated and has the status "Ready for Translation". When I want to publish the item, I get the error: *Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details. Error ID: 2115710291-450043 (29209841)*

What is the problem? I cannot translate News and News (Detail).

Side note: I'm working in the test environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Internal Server Error - What's in a GACK?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161605/internal-server-error-whats-in-a-gack)