# Gack during package deployment

Tags: gack

The following error was received while deploying an unlocked package
error code: 417422326-17190 (1733734233).

I have tried to re-deploy but received same error.

Comment: You're going to need to open a ticket with Salesforce's official customer support for this one (unless you're lucky enough to find information for the part of the id in the parenthesis).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Internal Server Error - What's in a GACK?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161605/internal-server-error-whats-in-a-gack)

Comment: what are the steps you are following to retry? Are you using pipeline mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

An Investigation *#W-15138579* has been logged for above gack and the issue is related to dependency not being installed in the build org at the time of package version creation and the workaround for that is to retry creating the version of the package after some time.